# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: main error after installing app

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to modify an deprecated code but creating a same project with same package id I'm able to run the code now it crashing every time when run on main screen subscription function which is call which is shown in below screenshot [this image contain screenshot of main activity where subscription function called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqlFA.png) this is the context from where it called [this screenshot is from where the context called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvj9Q.png) its subscription file

MainActivity.java

```
package com.appstone.buildupyourvoice;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.enums.TypeType;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.FavouritesFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.FocusFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.LevelFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.MenuFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.ModeFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.SettingsFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.StatisticsFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.SubscriptionFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.fragments.TypeFragment;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.model.Challenge;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.model.WorkoutData;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.enums.FocusType;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.enums.LevelType;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.MenuViewModel;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.enums.ModeType;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.model.WorkoutStorage;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.TrainingUtilities;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.subscription.SubscriptionUtil;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import jp.wasabeef.picasso.transformations.BlurTransformation;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentContainerView fragContainer;

    public MenuFragment menuFragment;
    public StatisticsFragment statisticsFrgment;
    public SettingsFragment settingsFragment;
    public SubscriptionFragment subsFrag;

    ImageView background;

    ModeFragment modeFragment;
    LevelFragment levelFragment;
    FocusFragment focusFragment;
    TypeFragment typeFragment;
    public FavouritesFragment favouritesFragment;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    AlertDialog dialog;

    MenuViewModel viewModel;

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        Intent i = result.getData();
        if (i == null) {
            // 14.10.22: We currently don't know why this is null sometimes, but we want to prevent
            //           the app from crashing and send the event to crashlystics.
            return;
        }
        long currentUnixTime = i.getLongExtra("start_time", 0);

        ArrayList<Challenge> challenges = new ArrayList<>();
        String cString = i.getStringExtra("challenges");
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(cString);
            Challenge[] challengeArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), Challenge[].class);
            challenges = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(challengeArray));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //TODO update the created training here
        WorkoutData last = null;
        for (WorkoutData w : Objects.requireNonNull(viewModel.getWorkouts().getValue())){
            if (last == null) {
                last = w;
            }else if(w.getDate()>last.getDate()){
                last = w;
            }
        }

        WorkoutData w = new WorkoutData(currentUnixTime, i.getLongExtra("train_dur", 0), i.getLongExtra("duration", 0), TypeType.getActiveType(this), ModeType.getActiveMode(this), LevelType.getActiveLevelID(this), FocusType.getActiveFocusIDList(this), challenges);

        WorkoutStorage.updateWorkoutTime(w.getDate(), w);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                statisticsFrgment.reloadWorkouts();
            }
        });
    });


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        if (!isTablet()) {
//            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Make to run your application only in portrait mode
//        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        initSubscription();

        background = findViewById(R.id.background_iv);
        background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#66FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(R.drawable.close_up_of_finger_of_a_childs_hand_resting_on_piano_keys)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .transform(new BlurTransformation(this, 90, 1))
                .into(background);

        fragContainer = findViewById(R.id.container);
        menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        statisticsFrgment = new StatisticsFragment(this);
        settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.container, menuFragment, null)
                    .commit();
        }
        //Show tutorial on first open
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!sp.getBoolean("start_shown", false) || !sp.getBoolean("updated_start_shown", false)) {
            sp.edit().putBoolean("start_shown", true).apply();
            sp.edit().putBoolean("updated_start_shown", true).apply();
            launchStartActivity();
        }

        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.training);
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this::onBottomNavigationItemSelected);
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(this::onBottomNavigationItemReselected);

        // disabling the tooltip on long press
        for (int j = 0; j < bottomNavigation.getMenu().size(); j++) {
            MenuItem item = bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(j);
            View view = bottomNavigation.findViewById(item.getItemId());
            view.setOnLongClickListener(x -> true);
        }

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MenuViewModel.class);

    }

    public void launchStartActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_down_in, R.anim.from_down_in);
    }

    public boolean onBottomNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.training){
            showTabFragment(menuFragment);
        } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.statistics){
            showTabFragment(statisticsFrgment);
        }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            showTabFragment(settingsFragment);
        }

        bottomNavigation.removeBadge(item.getItemId());

        return true;
    }

    public void onBottomNavigationItemReselected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("Backstack", "entry count = " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        Log.d("Backstack", "entry count after = " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
//
//        View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.main_scrollview);
//        if (scrollView instanceof ScrollView)
//            ((ScrollView) scrollView).fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
//        else
//            ((NestedScrollView) scrollView).fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

    }

    // Switch to a different BottomNavigation Tab
    public void showTabFragment(Fragment f) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, f)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onClickMode() {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        modeFragment = new ModeFragment();
        modeFragment.setEnterTransition(slide);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, modeFragment, null)
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack(null) // name can be null
                .commit();
    }

    public void onClickLevel() {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        levelFragment = new LevelFragment();
        levelFragment.setEnterTransition(slide);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, levelFragment, null)
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack(null) // name can be null
                .commit();
    }

    public void onClickFokus() {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        focusFragment = new FocusFragment();
        focusFragment.setEnterTransition(slide);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, focusFragment, null)
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack(null) // name can be null
                .commit();
    }

    public void onClickTrain(List<Challenge> responseList) {
        //TODO create training here with zero time
        ArrayList<Challenge> cArray = new ArrayList<Challenge>(responseList);

        long currentUnixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        WorkoutData w = new WorkoutData(currentUnixTime, 0, TrainingUtilities.getTrainingDuration(cArray), TypeType.getActiveType(this), ModeType.getActiveMode(this), LevelType.getActiveLevelID(this), FocusType.getActiveFocusIDList(this), cArray);
        WorkoutStorage.saveNewWorkout(w);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                statisticsFrgment.reloadWorkouts();
            }
        });
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrainingActivity.class);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        i.putExtra("challenges", gson.toJson(cArray));
        i.putExtra("start_time", currentUnixTime);
        mGetContent.launch(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_down_in, R.anim.empty_transition);
    }

    public void onModeChosen(int mode) {
        menuFragment.refreshViews(this);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (favouritesFragment != null) {
            favouritesFragment = null;
        }
        if (focusFragment != null) {
            focusFragment = null;
            menuFragment.refreshViews(this);
        }
        if (menuFragment == null) {
            menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
            menuFragment.refreshViews(this);
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.container, menuFragment, null)
                    .commit();
        }
//        if (trainingFragment != null) {
//            trainingFragment.viewModel.countDownTimer.cancel();
//            trainingFragment.viewModel.playing = false;
//            trainingFragment.stopPlaying();
//            trainingFragment.viewModel.reset();
//            trainingFragment = null;
//        }
    }

    public void openFavourites() {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        favouritesFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
        favouritesFragment.setEnterTransition(slide);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, favouritesFragment, null)
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack(null) // name can be null
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SubscriptionUtil.shared.checkForPurchases();
        if (favouritesFragment != null) {
            onBackPressed();
            favouritesFragment = null;
        }
//        if (trainingFragment != null && !MainApplication.haveNetworkConnection()) {
//            trainingFragment.stopPlaying();
//            trainingFragment.onMediaPlayerError();
//        }
    }

    private boolean isTablet() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        float yInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi;
        float xInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
        double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(xInches * xInches + yInches * yInches);
        // 6.5inch device or bigger
        // smaller device
        return diagonalInches >= 6;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull @NotNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    public void showSubsOffers() {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        subsFrag = new SubscriptionFragment();
        subsFrag.setEnterTransition(slide);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, subsFrag, null)
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack(null) // name can be null
                .commit();
    }

    public List<WorkoutData> getWorkoutsThisWeek(){
        return statisticsFrgment.getWorkoutsThisWeek(Objects.requireNonNull(statisticsFrgment.viewModel.getWorkouts().getValue()));
    }

    private void initSubscription() {
        SubscriptionUtil.shared.setActivity(this);
    }

    public void onClickType() {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        typeFragment = new TypeFragment();
        typeFragment.setEnterTransition(slide);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, typeFragment, null)
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack(null) // name can be null
                .commit();
    }

//    public void setTrainBtn() {
//        menuFragment.setTrainBtn();
//    }
}
```

subscription.java

```
package com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.subscription;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult;
import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase;
import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.MainApplication;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.R;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.Security;
import com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.Utilities;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED;

public class Subscription {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Subscription";

    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_SKU_ID = "premium_user";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_3_MONTH_SKU_ID = "premium_user_3_month";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_12_MONTH_SKU_ID = "premium_user_12_month";
    private static final List<String> SUBSCRIPTION_SKUS = Arrays.asList(SUBSCRIPTION_SKU_ID,
            SUBSCRIPTION_3_MONTH_SKU_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_12_MONTH_SKU_ID);

    private Activity activity = null;
    private BillingClient billingClient;
    private List<SkuDetails> availableProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Purchase> purchases = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean connected = false;
    private SkuDetails downgradeTo = null;

    /**
     * Whether the user has entitlement to use premium features.
     * <p>
     * Attention: Does not state whether there is an active Subscription or just a cancelled one,
     * which is still active till the subscription period is over.
     */
    private boolean premium = false;


    public Subscription() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(MainApplication.getAppContext())
                .setListener((this::onPurchaseUpdated))
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build();

        startConnection();
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void enablePremium() {
        if (premium) return;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Premium is now enabled");
        this.premium = true;
    }

    public void disablePremium() {
        if (!premium) return;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Premium is now disabled");
        this.premium = false;
    }

    public void togglePremium() {
        this.premium = !premium;
    }

    public boolean isPremium() {
        getSubscriptionPurchase(); // Updating if the sub has expired
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Premium status:" + premium);
        return this.premium;
    }

    /**
     * Try to build a connection to the Google Play center.
     */
    private void startConnection() {
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    connected = true;
                    SubscriptionUtil.billingAvailable = true;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Successfully connected to Google Play Servers");
                    checkForPurchases();
                    queryAvailableProducts();
                } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE) {
                    SubscriptionUtil.billingAvailable = false;
                } else
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Negative billingResult response code: [" + billingResult.getResponseCode() + "] " + billingResult.getDebugMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                connected = false;
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection lost to the GooglePlay Billing Service");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Trying to reconnect ...");
                startConnection();
            }
        });
    }

  }
```

I'm getting this errors

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appstone.buildupyourvoice, PID: 18438
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.MainActivity.initSubscription(MainActivity.java:386)
    at com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please provide a valid Context.
    at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient$Builder.build(com.android.billingclient:billing@@6.1.0:1)
    at com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.subscription.Subscription.<init>(Subscription.java:66)
    at com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.utilities.subscription.SubscriptionUtil.<clinit>(SubscriptionUtil.java:36)
    at com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.MainActivity.initSubscription(MainActivity.java:386) 
    at com.appstone.buildupyourvoice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

i dont know why this error is coming and how can i solve this i tried to remove context but its not working

Comment: You made a mistake in `Subscription.<init>(Subscription.java:66)`. Show us that code and what surrounds it.